# Non-flat locus for smooth schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$, $Y$ be connected smooth schemes of finite type over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a non-birational morphism surjective on underlying topological spaces. Can the non-flat locus of $f$ be non-empty of codimension$\geq 2$ in $X$? For birational morphism, I belive ZMT plus a purity theorem show that the answer is "no".